# Python/JSON parsing error in Flask REST API

Tags: python, json, flask

Here is the data I send in:

```
   {
    "customer": {
        "CustomerName": "John Doe",
        "PhoneNumber": "123-234-5678",
        "FaxNumber": "123-234-5678",
        "WebsiteURL": "http://www.something.com",
        "Delivery": {
            "AddressLine1": "One Microsoft Way",
            "PostalCode": "98052"
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I receive:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Here is the code that processes the request:

```
def put(self):
    args = parser.parse_args()
    customer = json.loads(args['customer'])
    result = self.executeQueryJson("put", customer)
    return result, 201
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You would receive that error if "customer" were not surrounded by double-quotes.  Are you certain that the input to your code matches the example json in your post?

Comment: Yes, I've validated and linted this many times. I am using Postman if that helps.

Comment: args['customer'] is this:
{'CustomerName': 'John Doe', 'PhoneNumber': '123-234-5678', 'FaxNumber': '123-234-5678', 'WebsiteURL': 'http://www.something.com', 'Delivery': {'AddressLine1': 'One Microsoft Way', 'PostalCode': '98052'}}

Comment: JSON requires double quotes for strings.  The example you gave in your comment has single quotes for the strings.